# How can I plot a function and its partial sums?

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Plot an Infinite Series](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14083/how-to-plot-an-infinite-series)
>   [Coding mistake?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17391/coding-mistake)

I have *Mathematica* v9.0 and I am a newbie to *Mathematica*. I am trying to plot a function $f(x)=x$ over the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. Together on the same plot, I want two partial sums, $S_{4}$ and $S_{8}$.

I have tried to plot $S_{4}$ and $f(x)$, but can't seem to get it right. Can anyone show me how to do it? Here is my code:

```
f[x_] = x
s[n_, x_] := Sum[((-1)^(n + 1)) (2/n) (Sin[nx]), {n, 1, Infinity}] 
partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 1, 4}]; 
Plot[Evaluate[f[x], partialsums], {x, -3, 3}]
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Hope someone can shed light on this.

Comment: Try `f[x_] := x
s[k_, x_] := Sum[((-1)^(n + 1)) (2/n) (Sin[n x]), {n, 1, k}]
partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, {4, 8, 12}}];
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], partialsums}], {x, -3, 3}]`! You are making some syntax errors. By the way think if you sum up to infinity can it be called a partial sum?

Comment: Thanks a lot @PlatoManiac! Currently we have like {n,1,8} if I change this to {n,4,4}, the graph will just have $f(x)=x$ and $S_{4}$ partial sum. How can I adjust the code so that only the function and $S_{4}$ and $S_{8}$ appear on the graph only without going from 1 to 8? And how can I change the lines of $S_{4}$ to dotted line while $S_{8}$ to dot type because when I print it in black and white, it will be easier to differentiate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14083/5

Comment: @Sandra you are welcome. In my comment I plot $\{f,S_4,S_8,S_{12}\}$!

Comment: @Hypnotoad - Thanks for giving me the link and sorry for the duplicate. I am very new to this forum. Let assured that duplicate will not occur again. Thanks again for pointing this out.

Comment: @PlatoManiac - Oops. Once again thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: @Sandra No worries :) Welcome to Mathematica.SE, by the way!